# Entity Framework - How to ignore errors in automatic migrations

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an application using SQLCE4 and Entity Framework. The application has some migrations that haven't been applied for a specific user. Somehow the database has a column even though EF says the migration hasn't been applied. So when I try to run the application, I get the error `A column ID occurred more than once in the specification.`

I looked at the database `sdf` file and found the column that already existed and correlated it with the line that was trying to add it.

```
AddColumn("dbo.ReceiveElements", "PackingSlipID", c => c.String(maxLength: 4000));.
```

The database somehow already has the column `PackingSlipID`. I am playing a huge guessing game here and thinking that perhaps the user closed the application while the database update / migration was in progress. (Not sure if this is possible.)

**The Problem**

If I remove the line above, the update works fine and the database runs fine. However, I need to leave the line there because it creates a proper update scenario. I tried wrapping the code in a try / catch and the issue still happens. How do I prevent the error from crippling the rest of the migration? I would settle for a way of checking if the column exists before calling "AddColumn" although I'd prefer not to modify the migration code.

The database is set to migrate automatically using

```
Database.SetInitializer<Data.DataManager>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Data.DataManager, Migrations.Configuration>());
```

Comment: A few things to look at: (1) The class itself may be in conflict with what a migration says. (2) You can roll back migrations quite easily. Copy things over to a sandbox box and roll things way back. (3) Start over with the class today as you want it, and NO migrations (historically). You should know how to remove the rows in the migration table, or delete the table entirely, based on what other things are in there... (3) sounds like the one I would do first...

Comment: @PatTrainor This is an application deployed to a number of handheld devices. The application works on every device except for one. So the migrations work and the class is set up properly.

Comment: So are you saying that the client itself is out of sync, as it has a local copy, and the global update didn't work for just this one? If so, then what is preventing either a re-install (export to preserve data, then import after update/reinstall, of course)? It sounds like you do your EF migrations centrally, then the apps deal with the schema changes, and their own assemblies are upgraded as usual. So if so, the local DB on the client is out of sync, right? What is preventing you from rebuilding it on the client?

Comment: @PatTrainor I can do it manually or reinstall the app, but the preference here is to not lose the local data that device has and avoid support calls for this issue. I can look into exporting and re-importing the data automatically.

Comment: (1 of 2) hmm.. can you implement a type of data recovery centrally, so the client sends the (unique) data to you? You can then have them re-install (or initiate it remotely (I know nothing of your app/architecture)... The you can re-import/send to the app without the client having to mess with it... Makes it tough that you can't get to the client remotely. I'm writing a similar client/server app now, and I've been thinking about how to deal wit these situations as well.

Comment: (2 of 2) Perhaps you can write a web service (how I'm doing it) that will help you fix the client, then write a quick & dirty exe that can be run locally that will do the backup & restore, but back up the data at the central site just in case that messes up. Then you can so an ALTER TABLE and manually re-index, or validate schema, maybe even send you more data on the state of the client to help further troubleshoot. Sorry I don't know enough about your unique situation to offer an answer.. :(

Comment: @PatTrainor Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that's a viable option here. I'll look into it and other ideas, though.